# New PFObject via PFUser

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

i registered a User with PFUser and now i want to add a PfObject for each User something different, so like User A has in the PFObject the number 5 and User B has in the Object the number 8. How can i do that ? I used the PFSignUpViewController sample from Parse

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Objective-c, use this code to create a random number.

```
int r = arc4random_uniform(74);
```

Then save the r to the user, the same way you save username and password.

```
user[@"randomnumber"] = r;
```

All users have a objectId in parse, so i don´t see the point in doing what you are doing. And most of the information you need can be found in the docs.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users